# Web app occasionally gets net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I created a simple web app card game that is currently in development mode.

The way it works is simple: users log in and start playing. To play, the user clicks on three cards that make a match and clicks submit. Submit sends the names of the chosen cards to the server to be saved. Then the next round is loaded and presented.

However, in testing, some of my users are getting stuck in the game after clicking submit.

An investigation in the console reveals a message:

```
POST https://myproj.herokuapp.com/api/user/billy/saveResult 
net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. The save mechanism works for other rounds. Why does this randomly happen suddenly to some rounds?

Any ideas?

Comment: I came across similar error when I was having network issues. If you in a wireless environment check whether you get a constant access to network. In addition the DNS server should be available throughout. This is the DNS resolution error throws out as this message.

Comment: Any idea how to fix?

Comment: In order to get the IP just try the below. `ping herokuapp.com`

Comment: @Aviro yes but what about `myproj.heroku.com`?

Comment: Well, it will follow the same IP address. However, the exact IP should be used if and only of your DNS resolution is not working. If you under a personal network (personal wifi) try to configure a third party DNS server. Get some help from the internet service provider on this regards. If you under a co-operate network your system admin should be able to help on this.

Answer (score 1):

`ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` is given when the request can not reach the `DNS` server and therefore can not translate the given name into an IP sequence. This might be given to a bad connection to internet resulting to null network service, for example.

You could try to point directly to the IP address, so the request does not need to be translated and can be pointed direclty to the server. So instead of having:

```
POST https://myproj.herokuapp.com/api/user/billy/saveResult
```

You could try:

```
POST https://54.225.236.39/api/user/billy/saveResult
```

Please, also note that this could also be caused by a wrong `Proxy Settings` SetUp in case you have one.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hmmm thanks. Any ideas where I can find the IP address of my app?

Comment: I've posted it in my reply, it's `54.225.236.39`. You can check it trough `terminal` or `cmd` using `ping` instruction @Imray

Comment: how did you get that IP? I tried `ping https://myproj.herokuapp.com` but I get `Ping request could not find host`

Comment: Here you can find my request in the `terminal` [link](http://i61.tinypic.com/2m2g7co.png) @Imray

Comment: @LIogari so strange, I get `Ping request could not find host https://myproj.herokuapp.com. Please check the name and try again.`

Comment: It sounds to me that there is some kind of issue in your server that produces down times on it. Check if the server configuration is okay and if everything is running correctly. @Imray